# I got Error While i am trying to store data into session using @SessionAttribute Spring MVC anotation

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Here is my JSP file.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
         pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Project Manager</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<spring:url value="/resources/css/bootstrap-select.min.css"/>" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<spring:url value="/resources/css/global.css"/>" type="text/css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="<spring:url value="/resources/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"/>"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <jsp:include page="../Views/fragments/header.jsp"></jsp:include>

            <div class="container">

                <div class="row">
                    <h1>Resource</h1>
                </div>
<spring:url value="/resource/resource_review" var="formUrl"/>

        <form:form action="${formUrl}" method="POST" modelAttribute="resource">

            <div class="row">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="resource-name">Name</label> 
                    <form:input path="name" cssClass="form-control" id="resource-name"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="resource-type">Type</label> 

                    <form:select path="type" items="${select}" cssClass="selectpicker"/>

                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="cost">Cost</label> <input id="cost" type="text"
                        class="form-control" name="cost" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="unit">Unit of Measure</label> 
                    <form:radiobuttons path="unitOfMeasure" id="unit" items="${radioButton}"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="indicators">Indicators</label> 
                    <form:checkboxes id="indicators" path="indicator" items="${checks}"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="notes">Notes</label> 
                    <form:textarea id="notes" path="notes" class="form-control" rows="3"/>
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>

            </div>

        </form:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

@Controller Java file is here

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package org.controller;

import Project.Entity.resource;
import java.io.Serializable;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;

/**
 *
 * @author Queue
 */

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/resource")
@SessionAttributes("resource")
public class ResourcesController implements Serializable  {

    @RequestMapping("/add")
    public String add(Model model)
    { 
        return "resource_add";
    }

    @ModelAttribute("resource")
    public resource getResource()
    {
        System.out.println("Here is getResource method are invoked");
      return new resource();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/resource_review")
    public String review(@ModelAttribute resource resource)
    {
        return "resource_review";

    }

    @ModelAttribute("radioButton")
    public List<String> getRadio()
    {
       return new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{
                "Hours", "Piece", "Tons"    
            }));
    }
    @ModelAttribute("select")
    public List<String> getSelect()
    {
       return new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(new String[] {
                "Material", "Other", "Staff", "Technical Equipment" }));
    }
    @ModelAttribute("checks")
    public List<String> getCheck()
    {
       return new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{
                "Lead Time", "Special Rate", "Requires Approval"    
            }));

    }

    @RequestMapping("/save")
    public String save(@ModelAttribute resource resource) {
        System.out.println(resource);
        return "redirect:/resource/add";
    }


}
```

Here is Error Details i  have got.

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: setAttribute: Non-serializable attribute with name resource

```
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: add your `resource` class, it should implement `Serializable` NOT your controller.

Comment: ya...i got it i forget to put parameter into the getResource method ex public void getResource(@ModelAttribute resource resource)

Answer (score 0):

Go to your class definition and implement Serializable like this:

```
public class YourClass implements Serializable
```

Comment: not to your controller, i was referencing to your object model if you don't have a model java.util.List already implements java.io.serializable